# How to Plot only documents with the latest time with Vega-Lite?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite, graph-visualization

I have an index with a time field- 'Time', and for each 'Time' value there are multiple documents.
I want to present only the results of the latest time. how can I do it?
Is there a way to calculate the maximum value of the time field over all documents, and then apply a filter based on this value?

here is an example of the code:

```
{
  $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json

  data: {
    data: table
    url: {
      %context%: true
      %timefield%: Time
      index: data*
      body: {
        size: 10000
        _source: ["X", "Y"]
      }
    }
    format: {property: "hits.hits"}
  }
  mark: {type: "square", filled: true, size: 800 }
encoding: {
    x: {
      field: "_source.X"
      type: quantitative
      axis: {title: "X"}
    }
    y: {
      field: "_source.Y"
      type: quantitative
      axis: {title: "Y"}
    }  
}
}
```

I tried this code, and it is still not working.
I guess my syntax is incorrect?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
  "data": {
    "data": "table",
    "url": {
      "%context%": true,
      "%timefield%": "Time",
      "index": "data*",
      "body": {
        "size": 10000,
        "aggs": {
          "time_field": {
            "terms": {"field": "Time", "size": 1, "order": {"_key": "desc"}},
            "aggs": {
              "x_Field": {"terms": {"field": "X", "size": 10000}},
              "y_Field": {"terms": {"field": "Y", "size": 10000}}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "format": {"property": "aggregations.category.buckets[0].x_Field.buckets"}
        "format": {"property": "aggregations.category.buckets[0].y_Field.buckets"}

  },
  "mark": {"type": "square", "filled": true, "size": 800},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x_Field", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"title": "X"}},
    "y": {"field": "y_Field", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"title": "Y"}}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your time field in descending order with size 1 which will give you the documents belonging to the latest time, then you will need to change the format as per the elasticsearch output.
Below is the sample code for elastic search:

```
 "body": {
    "size": 10000,
    "aggs": {
        "time_field": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "Time",
                "size": 1,
                "order": {
                    "_key": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "x_Field": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "x",
                        "size": 10000
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: You can get flattened x-field data in key after using this below format.

```
  "format": {
        "property": "aggregations.category.buckets[0].x_Field.buckets"
    }
```

Comment: thank you! but then how can I approach the X and Y fields in the "encoding" section?

Comment: I have added an edit in my answer, which will give you the flattened bucket array for your x fields, in similar way you can get it for y fields.

Comment: I tried to add this to my code, but I guess I did it wrong (I edited my question and added it). Can you help me find the problem?

Comment: Yes its incorrect. First, only try with x-axis. And try your example in vega-lite editor first. Also check for elastic search examples over google.